# Recursive queue job, 100% CPU usage

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a queue job that runs continuously, i.e. runs a new job after the previous job has finished.

I've created a skeleton job just to test out the performance of doing this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use App\Models\Page;

class PageParser extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    protected $page;

    public function __construct(Page $page)
    {
        $this->page = $page;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->delete();
        dispatch(new PageParser($this->page));
    }
}
```

I ran the queue listenener, and immediately my CPU usage jumped to 100% and stayed at that level indefinitely.

Why is it using 100% of my CPU? Is there any way to fix this? Does `ShouldQueue` have anything to do with this?

Comment: I'm confused, what should the expected behavior be? Continuously running a job sounds to me like running 100% of the CPU. Did you want to allocate that time elsewhere, or how did you want to throttle the job down?

Comment: Well if I ran the job once, it makes sense for it to use very very little CPU usage, given that no computations are being done other than re-running the job. So why then does the CPU usage skyrocket if it's run more than once, when alone it uses barely any of the CPU? Are queues run synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: How else should it run? Consider that there is no hidden throttle, how often should your loop run? Right now, it is going to run as often as possible. As often as possible = 100% CPU usage.

Comment: It should run as often as possible but it doesn't make sense to me why it would use 100% of the CPU. If I run it once and, let's say, it uses 1% of my CPU, and then it finishes and calls the same job again, why doesn't it consistently use just 1%?

Comment: @Thebluefish is correct. According to you, you said you want the start to immediately call the same job again, so basically your task starts but never stops.. It's going to use every cpu cycle it can get obviously. You should use sleep if you're just testing, or base the running ability based on time, e.g. minutes, seconds, etc.